# Getting total word count from a string series in a Pandas Data Frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a 2-column Pandas data frame composed of tweets: the second column is the tweets themselves. I want to get a word count of all the tweets together.

Data Frame looks like so:

```
RT @PaulHaleAndMom: Four Hours After #Piedmont...
RT @NatPoliceAssoc: Body camera video shows At...   
RT @XLNB: When Spanish Drake and Jamaican Drak...
 I almost cried this morning. My babies are ...
@SebastianDanzig Hey Bassy are tickets and VIP...
```

The following is giving me the count by row.

```
wc_DF = tweets_DF['text'].apply(lambda x: Counter(x.lower().split()))
```

i.e.

```
{'rt': 1, '@paulhaleandmom:': 1, 'four': 1, 'h...
```

What would be a good vectorized implementation in Pandas be for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution if you want to stay in pandas assuming your string Series is referenced as `tweets_DF['text']`:

```
words = tweets_DF['text'].str.split()
word_counts = pd.value_counts(words.apply(pd.Series).stack())
```

`words` will be a Series of lists and you can convert to a DataFrame by running apply over the Series with the Series constructor. After that you can convert back into a (multi-indexed) Series containing each word as its value using `stack()`. Finally you can use `value_counts(..)` to count the observations returning a Series indexed on the word and counts as the values.

Answer (score 0):

Use `sum` and `Counter`

```
c = [ "RT @PaulHaleAndMom: Four Hours After #Piedmont...", "RT @NatPoliceAssoc: Body camera video shows At...","RT @XLNB: When Spanish Drake and Jamaican Drak..."]
from collections import Counter
Counter(pd.Series(c).str.split().sum())

Counter({'RT': 3,
         '@PaulHaleAndMom:': 1,
         'Four': 1,
         'Hours': 1,
         'After': 1,
         '#Piedmont...': 1,
         '@NatPoliceAssoc:': 1,
         'Body': 1,
         'camera': 1,
         'video': 1,
         'shows': 1,
         'At...': 1,
         '@XLNB:': 1,
         'When': 1,
         'Spanish': 1,
         'Drake': 1,
         'and': 1,
         'Jamaican': 1,
         'Drak...': 1})
```